# What would you call a function that takes T<A>[] as input and outputs T<A[]>?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, naming-conventions, naming

Some examples

```js
const f = <L, R>(xs: Either<L, R>[]): Either<L, R[]> => { throw new Error('Not Implemented') };
```

```js
const f = <T>(xs: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]> => { throw new Error('Not Implemented') };
```

```js
const f = <T>(xs: Box<T>[]): Box<T[]> => { throw new Error('Not Implemented') };
```

These all perform some sort of reducing. However, the semigroup here is just a List.

From a readability point of view, what would be some good names for such functions.

There is obviously some degree of subjectivity here, which is discouraged by SO. However, I feel it is also possible to say that a name is bad or good with some objective criteria/rationale.

maybe alone the line of `collect` or `gather`?

Comment: It’s probably [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript isn't Haskell, but that's where I usually go to see if there's already a well-known name for the type of thing I'm creating.

Assuming that `Either<L, T>`, `Promise<T>`, and `Box<T>` are all [applicative functors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor) over `T`, then the function signatures `<L,T>(x: Array<Either<L, T>>) => Either<L, Array<T>>`, `<T>(x: Array<Promise<T>>) => Promise<Array<T>>`, and `<T>(x: Array<Box<T>>) => Box<Array<T>>` would probably be called [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence).

A sketch of the rules for what makes a type function `F<T>` applicative functor over `T`: you need to have some functions that act like this:

```
declare function pure<T>(x: T): F<T>;
declare function lift2<A, B, T>(cb: (a: A, b: B) => T): (fa: F<A>, fb: F<B>) => F<T>;
```

And then `sequence` could be implemented like this:

```
function sequence<T>(x: Array<F<T>>): F<Array<T>> {
    return x.reduce(lift2<T[], T, T[]>((xs, x) => xs.concat(x)), pure([]))
}
```

For `Promise<T>` that's fairly straightforward:

```
function pure<T>(x: T): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve(x);
}
function lift2<A, B, T>(cb: (a: A, b: B) => T): (fa: Promise<A>, fb: Promise<B>) => Promise<T> {
    return (fa: Promise<A>, fb: Promise<B>) => fa.then(a => fb.then(b => cb(a, b)))
}
```

and you could presumably come up with ones for `Either<L, T>` and `Box<T>` too.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQHxQLxQAoCcD2BbASwGcJEkBuKAWAChaAzAVwDsBjYAnZqMRrU5AAoAHgC4oCAJTj4yKAG9aUZVH7A+3bPmIQAdPyI4ANgDcIIyeVoBfBi3aduRgvWAAmOAEEANFABCvkKsAEbiggCG4j5Qof6SaChSYfSRsF5IvvSx8H5I8agosiiKNCqqEOpY3IIpMumZ2XC5+SgpusAAFhDMEQlQWe1dPcF9IRG+wZJTNrR2bBxcUCQAjozdrAJIIlFYWOEgcEV5dZ67+2TFSipqGlDC+hAAJowbgs6uHggA2gC6gYG-LYiIi+YQtO5EXSsLiscLACySXy8fiCX7TGi2Og0FZrNjmL5aQgkB6GUzmACMiMwuCJegMxjMgjcVMJOhJDPMAGZJD9JINuoIAF6jLikvRGHAAcyFU3IQA)